# Python HTTPS-requests using azure AAD authentication token. Or python version of CreateAuthorizationHeader()

Tags: python, azure, api, python-requests

and thank you for you useful help already.

I am trying to make an API call using python. Sadly, the only documentation of the API is an implementation already existing in C#.

My problem is, that after i acquire an Azure AADTokenCredential object - i simply do not know how to use it in my HTTPS request.

```py
def get_data_from_api(credentials):
        serialNumber = "123456789"
        fromDate = "01/10/2019 00:00:00" # DD/m/YYYY HH:MM:SS
        untilDate = "09/10/2019 00:00:00" # DD/m/YYYY HH:MM:SS

        PARAMS = {
            serialNumber: serialNumber,
            fromDate: fromDate,
            untilDate: untilDate
        }
        url = "https://myapi.azurewebsites.net/api/sensordata/GetBySerialNumber"
        r = requests.get(url = url, header={"Authorization": credentials}, params=PARAMS)
        print(r)
        #data = r.json()
        return data
```

The credentials is an msrestazure.azure_active_directory.AADTokenCredentials retrieved using the adal package.
The above code results in an error as the header object can only be strings.
My question is - How do i pass the authorization object in the correct way?

The C# implementation looks like this:

```
            // Make a request to get the token from AAD
            AuthenticationResult result = Task.Run(async () => await authContext.AcquireTokenAsync(resource, cc)).Result;

            // Get the auth header which includes the token from the result
            string authHeader = result.CreateAuthorizationHeader();

            // ...

            // Prepare a HTTP request for getting data.
            // First create a client
            HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

            // Create the actual request. It is a GET request so pass the arguments in the url is enough
            HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(
            HttpMethod.Get, $"https://api.azurewebsites.net/api/sensordata/GetBySerialNumber?serialNumber={serialNumber}&from={fromDate}&until={untilDate}");

            // Add the required authorization header that includes the token. Without it the request will fail as unauthorized
            request.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("Authorization", authHeader);

            // Prepare the response object
            HttpResponseMessage response = Task.Run(async () => await client.SendAsync(request)).Result;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So yes! I finally solved it.

My problem was that i was passing on the ADAL object to the requests phase, however what I needed to do was pass on the actual token that is retrieved using: `'credentials = context.acquire_token_with_client_credentials(resource_uri,client_id,client_secret)'`.

Here credentials is a dictionary and what the requests needs in the header for authentication was:

```py
header = {
    "Authorization": "Bearer "+credentials["accessToken"]
}

r = requests.get(url=url, headers=header, params=PARAMS)
```

passing this on to the requests.get method worked!